# Local Normal Form of holomorphic map on Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $F:X \rightarrow Y $ be a holomorphic map defined at $p\in X$ , which is not constant. Then there is a unique integer $m \geq1$ which satisfies the following property: for every chart $\Phi_2:U_2 \rightarrow V_2$ on $Y$ centered at $F(p)$ , there there exists a chart $\Phi_1: U_1 \rightarrow V_1$  centered at $p$ such that $\Phi_2(F(\Phi_1^{-1}(z)))=z^m $.
The existence part of the question is fine .
How to prove uniqueness of $m\geq1$?
Reference ( Algebraic Curves and Riemann surfaces by Rick Miranda).

Comment: Can you please check my answer  @jakobian

Comment: I've only edited the tags so they don't include general topology. No need to ping me, it's not my area of expertise.

Comment: Okay no problem

Comment: It might be conceptually clearer to argue directly. In "classical" notation, if $z$ and $w$ are local coordinates with their origins at $p$, then in a neighborhood we have $z = \phi(w)$ for some holomorphic function $\phi$ with $\phi'(0) \neq 0$. Now substitute into the local representation of $F$ and find (the degree of) the lowest-degree term.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to give a proof of uniqueness of the integer $m\geq1$ . Verify if I am wrong. First observe that if there are local coordinate charts near p and F(p) such that F has the form  $z\in z^m$  then there are exactly m preimages of points near $F(p)$  in a neighborhood of $p$ . As $F$ is an open mapping therefore $F(U_1) \cap U_2$ is open in Y  , $ g =\Phi_2(F(\Phi_1^{-1}(z)))$ is holomorphic map which is again open map.
Therefore we can get a small enough neighborhood of $F(p)$ which has exactly m inverse images ,can be easily verified via commutative diagram. //
Therefore if we get two pairs of chart around $p$ and $F(p)$ for which $F$ locally looks like $z\rightarrow z^m $ and $z\rightarrow z^n $ respectively , $m \neq n$ then we will get a neighborhood around $p$ and $F(p)$ where some point has once $m$ preimages and $n $ preimages simultaneously. Which is absurd . therefore $m=n$.